# Google form to generate a unique value for each form submission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

On Google form submission, I am trying to get a unique patient id in column A automatically whenever there is a response being submitted. You can also see the formula in the formula bar.

[image]

As of now, I am able to do it with the following google script but due to the trigger limit, it is not getting fulfilled as the COVID response is quite higher and requests are keep coming in.

```
function myFunction1() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var lr=sheet.getLastRow()
  sheet.getRange(lr,1).setFormula('="PID"&row()-1');
}
```

[image]

If I add the formula to all cells in column A of this sheet, every time a new row is being inserted on form submission and the formula is NOT available for that row by default.

So, Is there a way that I can automate generating the PID automatically.? or any other smart ideas without the trigger option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative `ARRAYFORMULA` in cell A1:

`=arrayformula({"Patient Unique ID #";if(B2:B<>"","PID"&row(A2:A)-1,iferror(1/0))})`

`"Patient Unique ID #"` puts the title (Patient Unique ID #) in cell A1, then the `;` returns the line.

If B is not empty then generate the unique ID as per `"PID"` and a unique number based on `ROW()` less 1. If B is empty, then nothing `iferror(1/0)`.

Comment: The zero-length text string `""` is not a truly blank value. The formula in this accepted answer will insert empty text strings in column `A` all the way down to the end of the sheet. Keep that in mind if you are using functions like `counta()` or a script that uses `sheet.getDataRange()`. To avoid the issue, use `iferror(1/0)` instead of `""`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. If I got rid of `""` altogether, would that still result in a zero-length text string or do I definitely need `ifferror(1/0)`?

Comment: Using just a comma `,` will also give a truly blank value. I prefer to use the `iferror(1/0)` pattern to make it explicit.

Answer (score 1):

In Google Sheets, this sort of thing is usually done with an array formula. I would recommend that you leave the 'Form Responses 1' sheet as is and insert the timestamps in a new sheet with something like this:

cell `A1`:

```
=arrayformula( 
  ifs( 
    row('Form Responses 1'!A1:A)) = 1, "Patient ID", 
    isnumber('Form Responses 1'!A1:A), row('Form Responses 1'!A1:A) - 1, 
    true, iferror(1/0) 
  ) 
)
```

cell `B1`:

```
={ 'Form Responses 1'!A1:Z }
```

If you absolutely want to insert the Patient ID column directly in the form responses sheet, you may want to place it on the right after the columns that get updated by the form.

An array formula is more reliable than using a function that runs on a trigger, but do note that the patient IDs will be dynamic and only remain valid as long as no rows are inserted or deleted in the data. The same is true with your current approach.

To get static IDs, use an `on form submit` trigger that writes an ID on a row when that row is first submitted. See the [insertUniqueId_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/95223516?msgid=96190885) script for one example — it runs on an `on edit` trigger, but can be modified to run on an `on form submit` trigger.